# Start/Stop Services in Linux Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: services

I just installed PRTG Network Monitor on Linux Ubuntu 13.10 and I can't get it to start. How can I start/stop services in linux? like how you do in windows?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow this [guide](http://www.paessler.com/support/kb/questions/322) for the installation? It's was for Ubuntu 7.10, uses **wine** and doesn't sound very promising at all. Have you considered alternatives?

As far as Linux services are concerned, it is a good idea to have a look what's up and running using `service --status-all`. Services may be started using `sudo service start servicename`. You will ususally need root privileges for that.